# Cast C-style array of pointers to const

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am currently working with a C-API (OpenSSL) and there are a lot functions declared like the following:

```
// From bytes to TYPE
TYPE *d2i_TYPE(TYPE **a, unsigned char **ppin, long length);
// From TYPE to bytes
int i2d_TYPE(TYPE *a, unsigned char **ppout);
```

But sometimes, functions expect a pointer to an array of pointers to some const type:

```
// From bytes to TYPE
TYPE *d2i_TYPE(TYPE **a, const unsigned char **ppin, long length);
```

Notice the `const unsigned char **` vs `unsigned char **` and ignore the functions' first argument.

Now consider the following example, where some input data is given as non-const pointers. What is the correct way of casting the array of pointers to an array of pointers const? And also, since the function expects a pointer, the parameter must be an lvalue. I am guessing this is the reason there is no implicit cast..

```
int length = 42;
unsigned char * data = new unsigned char[length];

// Error C2664: cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned char **' to 'const unsigned char **'
TYPE * my_typeE = d2i_TYPE(nullptr, &data, length);

// My solution:
auto x = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char const *>(data);
auto y = const_cast<unsigned char const *>(data);
TYPE * my_typeX = d2i_TYPE(nullptr, &x, length);
TYPE * my_typeY = d2i_TYPE(nullptr, &y, length);
```

Are there other solutions that are possibly easier to read?

Comment: It is not necessary to explicitly use `reinterpret_cast` to get a `const unsigned char *` from an `unsigned char *`. That's overkill. Would you believe you can simply assign one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

No need of cast:

```
const unsigned char* z = data;
[[maybe_unused]]TYPE * my_typeZ = d2i_TYPE(nullptr, &z, length);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d57b1d672d0e990)